Fixed Repeating Output
Fixed Repeating Output is a challenge originally invented by Esolang user AnotherUser05 which shows that a language supports loops and I/O.
Challenge
A program that solves the challenge has to do these steps in order:

Reads a decimal integer x from any sort of input (e.g.: STDIN, file).
Then, print 1 for x times to any sort of output (e.g.: STDOUT, file).
Then, print 0 to any sort of output (e.g.: STDOUT, file). As an exception, outputting the 0 via exit code is not allowed because that would be unfair.

For example, if the input is 5, then:
1
1
1
1
1
0

and
111110

are both valid outputs, but
101111

is not a valid output.
A program doesn't have to output the 1's and the 0 to the same destination, but it still has to print the 1's first, then the 0. The behavior when x is negative is undefined.
This is code-golf, so shorter program wins.

What if x is 0? And does it explicitly have to be a program using input and output, or would just a function returning a string count?

When x is 0, it prints 0 because printing 1 zero times is the same as doing nothing. For the second question, I'm not the original author of the challenge so let's say that it counts.

How flexible is the output format? For example, in my language BitCycle, the straightforward method to input a decimal integer and output 1s and 0s would result in 1,1,1,1,1,0 as the output. What about 1 1 1 1 1 0? Or [1,1,1,1,1,0]?

Any unambiguous output format is allowed

Can I output the zero via exit code?

I don't think that's fair, because if you can do that, then this challenge will be the same as outputting x ones.

Vyxal, 2 bytes
ʀ>

Try it Online!
Outputs as a list.
Explained
ʀ>ṅ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ʀ    # ‎⁡                0..x
 >   # ‎⁢[x > n for n in     ]
  ṅ  # ‎⁣join into a single string


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Nekomata, 2 bytes
Ħ¬

Attempt This Online!
Ħ is a new built-in in Nekomata v0.5.1, so I am using the staging version of ATO.
Ħ¬      Take 5 as an example
Ħ       Histogram; generate a list where the ith element (0-indexed) is the number of times i appears in the input
            5 -> [0,0,0,0,0,1]
 ¬      Logical NOT
            [0,0,0,0,0,1] -> [1,1,1,1,1,0]


Python 2, 20 bytes
-3 byte thanks to @Jonathan Allan
print'1'*input()+'0'

Attempt This Online!
Python, 27 bytes
print('1'*int(input())+'0')

Attempt This Online!
Python, 25 bytes
print('1'*int(input()),0)

Uses a less strict output format. Thanks to @ayreguitar and @None1
Attempt This Online!

Not sure about this but could you use python -u and save the 4 bytes for the explicit 0?

@loopywalt, I don't see how -u would help implicitly outputting a zero; it seems to be for unbuffering output stream.

I was thinking of the exit code. OP seems to suggest something like that may be allowed. "A program doesn't have to output the 1's and the 0 to the same destination, but it still has to print the 1's first, then the 0." I just was unsure whether buffering might upset the correct order.

@loopywalt Buffering won't cause a problem with the order since python and most other programming languages flush output streams before exiting.

Making us of the 'Any unambiguous output format is allowed' in the original post comments, you can shave off 1 byte: print(' 1'*int(input()),0)

The number of characters can be further reduced by removing the space, because any unambiguous output format is allowed

@None1, Which space do you mean?

The only space in the program suggested by ayreguitar.

@None1, I have already removed that

Yes, but I removed it before you did.

@None1, Thanks; For future reference users here prefer comments over suggested edits

Brachylog, 4 bytes
⟦ṡᵐ↔

Try it online!
Unifies the output with a list, e.g. [1,1,1,1,1,0]
Explanation
⟦      Range [0, …, Input]
 ṡᵐ    Map sign: 
         The sign of positive integers is 1
         Thankfully for this challenge, the sign of 0 is 0
   ↔   Reverse the list


JavaScript (ES11), 16 bytes
-4 bytes thanks to @Unmitigated
Expects a BigInt and returns a string.
n=>10n**n/9n+"0"

Try it online!

You don't need to subtract 1: n=>10n**n/9n+"0"

@Unmitigated D'oh. Of course :) Thanks!

An alternative 16 that only works up to n=9 due to integer overflow: x=>10**-~x/9-1|0

JavaScript (Node.js),  25 bytes
-2 bytes thanks to @DLosc
x=>((2<<x)-2).toString(2)

Try it online!
Takes the number as the parameter to the function, then outputs the binary form of \$2^{x+1}-2\$

Nice approach! You can save two bytes with 2<<x

Quipu, 32 bytes
1&0&1&/\
--[]/\
1&3&0&
>===??
\/

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
A Quipu program is composed of threads, vertical 2-character-wide strips that act as code and also as value storage. Threads are, by default, executed one at a time left to right. Each thread's value starts at 0.
Thread 0 stores the current value of the loop counter:
1&
--  # Subtract 1 from the previous value of this thread
1&  
>=  # If the result is >= 0, jump to thread 1
\/  # Otherwise, read a number and set thread 0's value to that

Thread 1 checks whether the loop counter has hit zero:
0&
[]  # Load value of thread 0
3&
==  # If the result is == 0, jump to thread 3

Thread 2 is the loop body:
1&
/\  # Output 1
0&
??  # Jump back to thread 0

Thread 3 runs after the loop exits:
/\  # Output this thread's value (0 by default)


Perl 5 -p, 9 bytes
$_=1x$_.0

Try it online!

Great answer. Only improvement I can think of is to use -l060 and drop the .0 but it's kinda cheaty!

Knight (v2), 7 bytes
O+*,1P0

Try it online!
This answer takes full advantage of Knight's type coercion.
If you look at the code, you may notice that we seem to be multiplying (*) a list (,1) with a string (P), but due to type coercion, the second argument, which is P, is actually coerced to an integer, so this results in a list that consists of P 1's. Then, we seem to be adding the resulting list to an integer 0, but due to type coercion, the integer is coerced into a list, which, in this case, converts the 0 to a singleton list consisting of a 0. This singleton list is then concatenated at the end of the aforementioned list of 1's, resulting in a list of P 1's, followed by a single 0. Finally, O always coerces its input, which is a list, to a string, resulting in the list being joined by newline before being outputted to stdout.

Jelly, 3 bytes
>ŻY

A full program that accepts a (non-negative*) integer, \$x\$, and prints \$x\$ ones followed by a zero.
* negative integers will do the same as zero.
Try it online!
How?
>ŻY - Main Link: non-negative integer, X   e.g. 0      3
 Ż  - zero range                                [0]    [0,1,2,3]
>   - {X} greater than {that}?                  [0]    [1,1,1,0]
  Y - join with newline characters
    - implicit, smashing print


Haskell, 42 37 bytes
-5 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard.
main=do n<-readLn;print$10^n`div`9*10

Try it online!
Not math, 42 bytes
main=interact(\n->('1'<$[1..read n])++"0")

Try it online!

@WheatWizard How... imperative. :P Thanks!

BitCycle -u, 10 bytes
?~
v~v
>!<

Try it online!
This somehow works even though it uses some sketchy undefined behavior. It doesn't work on the Javascript online interpreter though, so it has to be modified for that interpreter:
16 bytes
?~
v~v
>v<
A/
 !

Try it online!

Undefined behavior FTW. :) Here's a 10-byte version that works in the JS interpreter.

@DLosc Ah, flipping it upside down. That's smart.

SQL (Oracle), 31 bytes
Always fun when we can slip an SQL solution that actual isn't that bad:
select lpad(0,&n+1,1)from dual;


Oracle version 23 now makes from dual optional!
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/nfcoa/application_development.html#GUID-85884-1:~:text=You%20can%20now%20run%20SELECT%20expression%2Donly%20queries%20without%20a%20FROM%20clause.

That's hilarious!!   and awesome!!

MathGolf, 3 bytes
Ä10

Try it online.
Explanation:
Ä    # Loop the (implicit) input-integer of STDIN amount of times,
     # using 1 character as inner code-block:
 1   #  Push a 1 every iteration
  0  # After the loop: push a 0
     # (after which the entire stack is joined and output implicitly as result)


Bash, 22 bytes
echo $((10**-~$1/9-1))

Attempt This Online!
Bash, 22 bytes
yes 1|head -n$1;echo 0

Attempt This Online!

99, 69 bytes
 999
99 9 9
9999 9 99 9






 9999 999
9
999 999 9
 9 99





9 99
9

Try it online!
This can 100% be golfed but it is very confusing to golf in this language, with all the 9's and all.
The main issue is this: the only way to access loops and conditionals in this language is through its GOTO command, which will conditionally GOTO a specified line. But because variables in 99 can only hold multiples of 9, so the GOTO command can only jump to lines with line numbers that are multiples of 9. That is why there is so much empty space between certain sections of the code: it is to accommodate for the limitations of the GOTO command.
For now, I am using a GOTO for lines 9 and 18, so that the loop starts at line 9, but I feel that there is a way to cut out the GOTO to line 18 and instead have a GOTO to line 0 (making the start of the loop at line 0), I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. The reason why I don't have a GOTO for line 0 is because line 0 is  999, which takes in input and sets it to the variable 999. If the input command was no-op after reading all the input, then I could have a GOTO to line 0, but instead it reads a 0 into the variable, which messes up the entire loop.
I'm also confident that re-arranging the way I assign the variables can also save 2 or 3 bytes, but I don't see anything for now.

Piet + ascii-piet, 18 bytes (2×9=18 codels)
tabitkcmA ?cjsc aa

Try Piet online!

If we didn't have to consider the x=0 case, there is a nice 14 bytes answer:
tkvnM?esuA Q??

Try Piet online!


Google Sheets, 13 bytes
=REPT(1,A1)&0


Acc!!, 87 86 82 bytes
N
Count i while _%96 {
_/96*960+_%48*96+N
}
Count i while _ {
_-960
Write 49-0^_
}

Try it online!
Explanation
Depends on the slightly unofficial behavior of the official interpreter, in which the input always ends with a newline character.
# Accumulator format: value * 96 + next_char
# Read first character
N
# Loop until next_char is EOF (0)
Count i while _%96 {
  # _/96*96*10   Multiply previous value by 10
  # +_%48*96     Add new digit to it (or 10 if character was newline)
  # +N           Read next character
  _/96*960+_%48*96+N
}
# For an input number X, the accumulator is now equal to (X * 10 + 10) * 96
# which is the same as (X + 1) * 960
# Loop until accumulator reaches 0
Count i while _ {
  # Decrement accumulator in steps of 960
  _-960
  # Output '1' if accumulator is still positive, '0' if it is now 0
  Write 49-0^_
}


Acc!!, 65 bytes
Count i while _%11-10 {
_*10+_%11+N%48
}
Write 49)*(_/11
Write 48

Try it online!
Abuses a bug in the official interpreter
Acc!!, 105 88 85 81 bytes
-5 byte thanks to @DLosc
Count i while _%11-10 {
_*10+_%11+N%48
}
Count i while _+1 {
Write 49-10/_
_-11
}

Try it online!

This is brilliant! Here's 87 bytes.

81 bytes

Wow, that's incredible! It took me quite a while to fully grasp all the details. I think I still don't get it all—probably need a few more minutes of staring at the code!

That's exactly how I felt reading your earlier solutions. ;) I used the same number-input algorithm over here, if you want to look at the explanation.

C (gcc), 49 bytes
-4 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat
main(c){for(scanf("%d",&c);~c;)putchar(49^!c--);}

Try it online!

In Floop, 110 bytes
s+n+@?[s-]n-s[-n@;]s+r[s-]s[s-n@+r+]s+r-[s-]r+s[o++++++++++n@-[s-]s[-r+]]s+r--[s-]r++s[n@+o-[s-]s[-r--n+@-n-]]

Try It Online! This was a massive pain to write. Takes about ten seconds for n=3.
This would be a fairly easy challenge even for a Turing tarpit like In Floop... if there was a print instruction. In Floop only outputs the value of the current variable on termination. So, we have to calculate the output value as a single integer by repeatedly adding 1 and multiplying by 10.
In Floop has four integer variables; n, o, r, and s; in addition to an arbitrarily large array of integers @ which can be indexed into by the variables. Unfortunately, the state machine I came up with for this has five, which I'll call input (@[1]), state (r), inv (s), acc (@[0]) and copy (o).
One other thing I should note is that In Floop can only check if a variable is nonzero, so I'll use the idiom s+r+[s-]s[-...] to check if a variable's zero a lot - Set s to 1, if condition's nonzero set it to 0, if s is nonzero set it to 0 and continue.
s+n+@?[s-]n-s[-n@;] # Termination check / setup
  n+@?    n-        # Try writing input value into input
s+    [s-]  s[-   ] # If it's zero
               n@;  # Print acc and terminate


s+r[s-]s[s-n@+r+] # Set up multiplication
s+ [s-]s[s-     ] # If 
  r               # State is 0 (start)
           n@+    # Increment acc
              r+  # State = 1 (multiplying)

s+r-[s-]r+s[o++++++++++n@-[s-]s[-r+]] # Multiply acc by 10
s+  [s-]. s[                        ] # If
  r-    r+                            # State is 1 (multiplying)
            o++++++++++               # Add 10 to copy
                       n@-            # Decrement acc
                          [s-]s[-  ]  # If acc == 0
                                 r+   # State = 2 (copying)

s+r--[s-]r++s[n@+o-[s-]s[-r--n+@-n-]] # Finish loop
s+   [s-]   s[                      ] # If
  r--    r++                          # State == 2 (copying)
              n@+                     # Increment acc
                 o-                   # Decrement copy
                   [s-]s[-         ]  # If copy is zero
                          r--         # State = 0 (setup)
                             n+@-n-   # Decrement input


TI-BASIC (TI-84+CE), 13 12 10 bytes

Removed one byte thanks to @KaiBurghardt.
Removed two bytes by not specifying the increment (which is an optional argument)

seq(X<Ans,X,0,Ans

This creates a list with the correct number of 1's and 0's. The byte count is subtracting any bytes that are present in an empty program. To find the byte count, I looked at the memory stats on the calculator. See how to score TI-BASIC for more information.
The input is in the form of the Ans variable, which needs to be set before running the program. Here is an example of input and output on the TI-84 Plus CE:


You will need to insert a Prompt Z. Currently, input via predefined variables is not accepted.

Given that a list is acceptable output, too, you can devise a list expression. For 12 Bytes you get seq(X<Ans,X,0,Ans,1 where Ans is the input to be entered prior program invocation.

@KaiBurghardt Oh, my bad, I'll fix that. Also good idea!

Unfortunately the increment is apparently not an optional argument in earlier versions of TI‑BASIC. My TI‑82 “Parcus” calculator raises an ERR:ARGUMENT error without it. Now you need to qualify TI‑BASIC to TI‑BASIC (TI‑84+CE) or whatever it is called. I’m not too familiar with TI‑BASIC and its entire history.

Confirmed this works on the slightly older TI-84 Plus C Silver Edition.

APL+WIN, 6 bytes
Prompts for integer input:
⌽0,⎕⍴1

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Retina 0.8.2, 7 bytes
.+
$*10

Try it online! Explanation: $* repeats a single character to its right, so the 0 does not get repeated. By default the repeat count is the entire match, which here is the input, so the input is replaced by the desired output.

Pip, 6 bytes
LqP1
0

Try it online!

The newline can be removed if you use one or both of the preset variables o (1) or i (0).

!@#$%^&*()_+, 28 bytes
>_(>+$!+!!+!+++n_*)+(!#_+)#

Try it online!
Input is a non-negative integer followed by the character "n". This is allowed as per this default I/O method (in this case, the input is actually an array of characters with the sentinel value being the character "n").
The character after the second ( is an ASCII 1 character.
The first loop is a golfed version of the "Input a Decimal Number" algorithm in this Esolangs article, using "n" as a sentinel value instead of a newline.

Could you save two bytes with null-terminated input?

@emanresuA hmm maybe, i might be able to cut out n_.

Well actually i would still need to push a 0 i think, so maybe 1 byte save

Ly, 5 bytes
R[Lu]

Try it online!
I found 5 different Ly programs that met the challenge in 6 characters.  Then I accidentally stumbled onto this one...
R      - generate a sequence from 0..N (from STDIN)
 [  ]  - loop while the top of stack is non-zero
  L    - "less than" compare top two entries (will be 1)
   u   - print the top of stack


Brainfuck+2, 11 bytes
;[>+:-<-]>:

Try it online
Explanation
; Input x as decimal number (only 0 to 255 are supported)
[ While x is nonzero
>+:-< Print 1
- Decrement x
]
>: Print 0


Ouroboros, 9 8 bytes
r+.!.!n(

Try it here! (You'll need to enter the code and input manually.)
Explanation
Due to some convenient coincidences, we can use a single snake for the program. Execution starts at the left end and proceeds to the right before looping back around to the beginning again. When the instruction pointer is on a character that gets swallowed, execution halts.

r reads an integer from input and pushes it to the stack. If there is no input remaining, it pushes -1 instead.
+ adds the top two items on the stack. Missing items are treated as 0.
.! duplicates the top of the stack and logically negates it (0 -> 1, anything else -> 0).
n outputs the top of the stack as a number.
( takes the top of the stack and eats that many characters from the end of the snake. Since execution is on the final character, if a nonzero number of characters is eaten, the program halts.

So: On the first iteration, r+ reads the input number and adds it to 0; on subsequent iterations, it pushes -1 and adds it to the existing number on the stack, decrementing it. .!.! pushes 0, then 1 if the stack number has not yet reached zero; otherwise, it pushes 1, then 0. n outputs the second of these numbers, and ( halts the program if the first is 1.

05AB1E, 3 4 3 2  bytes
crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(
Ý›

+1 byte as bugfix (L results in \$[1,0]\$ for edge-case \$n=0\$)
-1 byte thanks to @lyxal
-1 byte due to a comment of OP ("Any unambiguous output format is allowed"), so it'll output as a list
Try it online.
Explanation:
Ý   # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input of STDIN]
 ›  # Check for each value whether the (implicit) input is larger
    # (after which this list is output implicitly as result to STDOUT)


This fails the 0 test case, which should print 0, but prints 11 instead

@lyxal Sometimes L for $n=0$ can be pretty annoying in 05AB1E.. Should be fixed.

That's a hard language design choice imo. On one hand, [] is a sensible default because how can you have a range [0, 1]. But on the other hand, there's been times I would have like to have made that design decision to have it [1, 0] :p

Try it online! for 3 bytes

FreePascal, 58 B 54 B
Evidently, the output is just \$2^{x+1}-2\$ written to a base of two.
This is shorter than producing the desired output iteratively.
var x:word;begin read(x);write(binStr(1<<(x+1)-2,x+1))end.

−4 B:
As pointed out by dtanku, \$2^{x+1}-2 = 2^x2^1-2\$ so we pre‑evaluate \$2^1\$ and start exponentiating from \$2\$.
var x:word;begin read(x);write(binStr(2<<x-2,x+1))end.

NB:
The read and its sister procedures accept all integer literals acceptable in FreePascal source code, thus $F is valid input, too.

Can golf a bit further by replacing your 1 by 2 in the bitshift and removing (x+1).

Trilangle, 15 bytes
?<.>.(),/.!/'1!

Playground link
Issues warnings (in the online interpreter or with -w set) and exits with an error.
Unfolded:
    ?
   < .
  > . (
 ) , / .
! / ' 1 !

Roughly equivalent to this C code:
extern int get_int(); // Read stdin until an integer is found, then return that

int main() {
  int i = get_int();
  while (--i >= 0) {
    printf("%d\n", 1);
  }
  printf("%d\n", ++i);
  return 1;
}

Trilangle, no errors, 16 bytes
?<.>.(),/.!/'1!@

Playground link
Same idea as above, but add an exit opcode before it wraps around to the parts that error.

Uiua 0.10.0, 3 bytes
0¬⊚

-1 byte thanks to @noodle man
Returns a list of 1s then a 0.
Other solutions
Just to showcase other features in Uiua and different options for output.
0=.⇡
0↯:1
⇌±⇡+1
>⇡+1.
¬⋯ⁿ:2
⇌[@0⍥@1]
0⍥&p‿1
0⍥1      #cannot be bound to a function name


First one is in reverse order

You're right; I'll fix it

=.⇡ can be not where

tinylisp, 33 bytes
(d F(q((N)(i N(c 1(F(s N 1)))(q(0

Defines a function F that takes an integer and returns a list. Try it online!
(d F(q((N)(i N(c 1(F(s N 1)))(q(0))))))
(d F                                  ) ; Define F as
    (q(                             ))  ; a function
       (N)                              ; of one parameter, N:
          (i N                     )    ;  If N is truthy (nonzero):
              (c 1          )           ;   Prepend 1 to
                  (F       )            ;   the result of a recursive call
                    (s N 1)             ;   with argument N-1
                                        ;  Otherwise:
                             (q(0))     ;   A list containing a single 0

This solution has one major problem, the cardinal sin of lisp functions: it is not tail-recursive. For values of N above about 250, it gives a recursion error. So here is a tail-recursive function in 37 bytes that takes an integer, prints that many 1s, and returns 0:
(d F(q((N)(i N(i(disp 1)0(F(s N 1)))0

Try it online!
(d F(q((N)(i N(i(disp 1)0(F(s N 1)))0))))
(d F                                    ) ; Define F as
    (q(                               ))  ; a function
       (N)                                ; of one parameter, N:
          (i N                       )    ;  If N is truthy (nonzero):
                (disp 1)                  ;   Output 1 (returns nil, which is falsey)
              (i                   )      ;   If disp's return value is truthy:
                        0                 ;    0
                                          ;   Otherwise (which is always the case):
                         (F(s N 1))       ;    Recursive call with N-1
                                    0     ;  Otherwise, return 0

And here is a 40-byte tail-recursive anonymous function that returns a list, using some library functions:
(load library
(q((N)(map positive?(to0 N

Try it online!
(q((N)(map positive?(to0 N))))
(q(                         )) ; A function
   (N)                         ; of one parameter, N:
                    (to0 N)    ;  Range from N down to 0
      (map positive?       )   ;  For each, 1 if positive, 0 otherwise


Regenerate, 7 bytes
1{$~0}0

Attempt This Online!
$~0 is the first command-line argument. 1{$~0} repeats 1 that many times, and 0 adds a 0 on the end.

Thue, 252 bytes
N::=:::
9)::=)T9
8)::=)T8
7)::=)T7
6)::=)T6
5)::=)T5
4)::=)T4
3)::=)T3
2)::=)T2
1)::=)T1
0)::=)T
9|::=8|1
8|::=7|1
7|::=6|1
6|::=5|1
5|::=4|1
4|::=3|1
3|::=2|1
2|::=|11
1|::=|1
T|::=|T
1T::=T1111111111
()|::=P
PT::=P
P1::=P!1
!1::=~1
P0::=~0
::=
(N)|0


Try it online! (Note that the newline at the end of the input seems to be mandatory; otherwise, the interpreter doesn't read the last character of the input.)
Explanation
Thue is a non-deterministic string-rewriting language. The program comes in two parts: the top section, above the ::= line, is a list of rewriting rules, and the bottom section, below the ::= line, is the initial state. At every step, a rule that can be applied to the current state is picked at random and applied. Once no rules can be applied, the program halts.
Our initial state is:
(N)|0

to which the only rule that can be applied is the first one:
N::=:::

::: is a special replacement that reads a line of stdin. We now have our decimal input number within the parentheses.
9)::=)T9
...
1)::=)T1
0)::=)T

Move the rightmost digit outside of the parentheses and add a T marker indicating that everything to the left of it needs to be multiplied by 10.
9|::=8|1
...
2|::=|11
1|::=|1

Move the digit through the pipe character, converting to unary.
T|::=|T
1T::=T1111111111

Move T through the pipe character as well; anytime there's a 1 to its left, convert to ten 1s on its right.
()|::=P
PT::=P

Once the whole number has been converted, replace everything before it with P for printing mode.
P1::=P!1
!1::=~1

Any time P is followed by 1, insert ! before the 1; any time ! is followed by 1, remove both and output 1.
P0::=~0

Once all the 1s are gone, output 0.

BQN, 6 bytes
∾⟜0⥊⟜1

Try it at BQN online!
Explanation
∾⟜0⥊⟜1
    ⥊⟜1  # Reshape 1 to a length given by the function argument
          # I.e. create a list of (function argument) many 1s
∾⟜0      # Append a 0 to this list


I've tried in vain to find a more interesting approach that's shorter. Most end up being 7 bytes; a few are 6 bytes:
∾⟜0⋈⊐↕  # Get indices of range() in ⟨⟩, then append 0
«0∾⥊⟜1  # Reshape 1, prepend 0, shift left
×0∾˜⥊˜   # Reshape self, append 0, get sign of each

Try them
Given N, it's hard to make a list of length N+1 in BQN. The only builtin that does that is ⊔, but it requires its argument to be a list (thus wasting two bytes on ∘⋈), and it returns a list of lists, which is inconvenient to transform into a list of integers.

Charcoal, 4 bytes
×1Ｎ0

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: × is the repetition operator, so the string 1 is repeated according to the numeric input, and then the 0 is simply appended. Note that other ways of repeating 1 would cause it to become adjacent to the 0, which would require a separator character.

Ruby, 12 bytes
->n{?1*n+?0}

Try it online!

Whitespace, 55 bytes
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_n][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_n][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_END][S S S T    N
_Push_1][S N
S _Duplicate_1][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer_to_STDOUT][T  S S T   _Subtract_top_two][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_END][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer_to_STDOUT]

Letters S (space), T (tab), and N (new-line) added as highlighting only.
[..._some_action] added as explanation only.
Try it online.
Explanation in pseudo-code:
Integer n = STDIN as integer
Start LOOP:
  If (n == 0):
    Stop LOOP
  Print 1 (as integer to STDOUT)
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
Print n (which is 0 at this point) as integer to STDOUT


TacO, 8 bytes
@#*i
0 1

I believe this is optimal, even with the wasted #.
Try it online!

my first time playing with a 2D lang, so must have found like 30 different 8 byte solutions before I finally stumbled on a some real 7 byte solutions

JavaScript (Node.js), 18 bytes
n=>'1'.repeat(n)+0

Try it online!
JavaScript (Node.js), 19 bytes
f=n=>n?1+f(--n):'0'

Try it online!
。

*><>, 10 bytes
Uses the -i flag to pass in input.
:?1:n?!;1-

Explanation
:           Duplicate the top value on the stack
 ?1         Add 1 to the stack if the top value isn't zero         
   :        Duplicate the top value of the stack
    n       Print the top value as a number
     ?!;    Halt execution if the top value is 0
        1-  Subtract 1 from the top value

Try it online!

jq, 9 bytes
.*"1"+"0"

Try it online!

Zsh, 19 bytes
repeat $1 <<<1
<<<0

Try it online!

MarioLANG, 28 bytes
+>);[!:
="===#
 !:(-<
 #==="

Try it online!
Seems almost optimal, if not optimal.

F# (.NET 6+), 41 bytes
printf"%B"((2<<<int(stdin.ReadLine()))-2)

Most online compilers are too old (they can't format as binary), but this compiles on a proper IDE.

AWK, 27 bytes
{for(;$1+1;)print $1--?1:0}

Try it online!

24 bytes

Uiua, 3 bytes
¬°⊚

Explanation
 °⊚ # histogram (4 -> [0 0 0 0 1])
¬   # logical not ([0 0 0 0 1] -> [1 1 1 1 0])

```

PARI/GP, 12 bytes
n->10^n\9*10

Attempt This Online!
A function.

PARI/GP, 20 bytes
print(10^input\9*10)

Attempt This Online!
A full program.

Octave / MATLAB, 20 19 bytes
@(n)[~(1:n)+49 '0']

Try it online!

Brainfuck, 25 bytes (non-competing*)
-[>+<-----]>-->,[<.>-]<-.

Attempt This Online!
*: takes as input as a character-code, e.g. \x20 instead of 32.

Given the "decimal integer" phrasing, I'm not sure if character-code I/O is acceptable or if you're going to have to parse an integer from stdin digit-by-digit. However, if character-code I/O is acceptable, then it stands to reason you can output character codes 1 and 0 instead of ASCII digits 1 and 0...

@DLosc you are right, now that I read the challenge more carefully I don't think it's acceptable

Rust, 98 bytes
fn main(){print!("{}{}","1".repeat(std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap().parse::<usize>().unwrap()),0)}

Attempt This Online!

C++, 68 bytes (-9 by ceilingcat, and -1 yet again by Mukundan314)
#import<iostream>
main(int c){for(std::cin>>c;~c;)putchar(49^!c--);}

I'm…not even going to try to explain this. Ooh, XOR!
C++ (gcc), 78 bytes (-4 thanks to Mukundan314)
#include<iostream>
int main(){int c;for(std::cin>>c;c--;)puts("1");puts("0");}

Similar idea to the original, but using for loops and puts.
C++ (gcc), 82 bytes (OG)
#include<iostream>
int main(){int n;std::cin>>n;std::cout<<std::string(n,'1')<<0;}­⁡​‎‎

C++ syntax highlighting doesn't work. :(
Explanation
#include<iostream>
int main(){int n;std::cin>>n;std::cout<<std::string(n,'1')<<0;}­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁢⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­

#include<iostream>                                               # ‎⁡Imports the I/O library (char* haters be mad)
int main(){                                                   }  # ‎⁢Initiates the main() function.
           int n;std::cin>>n;                                    # ‎⁣Initializes variable n and reads it from STDIN.
                             std::cout<<                         # ‎⁤Prints things to STDOUT.
                                        std::string(n,'1')       # ‎⁢⁡This constructs a string with the char '1' repeated n times.
                                                          <<0;   # ‎⁢⁢Appends a 0 and ends the final line.


Created with the help of Luminespire.

forgot that garbage security is an option. thanks!

sed, 39 38 bytes
s/.*/echo {0..&}/e  #0 to n seperated by spaces
s/[^ ]//g           #only keep the spaces
y/ /1/              #spaces to 1s
a0                  #append a 0

Try it online!

Unfortunately I get an invalid command error: sed: 1: "/.*/echo ": invalid command code e Do some other side conditions have to be met? Please document so. I see you link GNU sed, but then I get the error sh: 1: sh: 1: cho: not found }/e: not found empty line 0.

@KaiBurghardt my req for 'it works' is 'it works on TIO'. I can't debug every possible implementation. if you want to be perfectly exact, --version on TIO says it uses sed (GNU sed) 4.5. if you want me to help you debug your specific problem, can you tell me exactly how you ran it here?

How dare you fuck the brain, 12 bytes
;^Iv
D^Nv)NH

Try it online

HDYFTB has no input so this is the reason why the amount of bytes is >12

EDIT: ; now exists so HDYFTB has input

Hi! Welcome to CGCC! I think you might find this to be a slightly more readable link.

yeah i did

Japt -R, 4 bytes
ò@gX

Try it
ò@gX     :Implicit input of integer U
ò        :Range [0,U]
 @       :Pass each X through the following function
  gX     :  Sign of difference with U


Python, 18 bytes
lambda x:"1"*x+"0"

Port of my Rust answer to Python.

Minkolang, 6 bytes
1nD0u.

Try it online!

PingPong, 15 bytes
;#/=\.@
1-/ \1.

Try it online!
I have another 15 bytes answer below, but I put this one at the top because I felt like this had to most golfing potential. I'm pretty confident the answer below is fully golfed using the strategies it employs.
15 bytes
;=\.@
0]\1.1-00

Try it online!

PowerShell Core, 13 bytes
,1*"$input"
0

Try it online!
Outputs to stdout and is newline separated
Uses the $input variable to access stdin
,1*"$input" # generate an array of 1 of the size of $input and print it
0           # print a zero


Scala 3, 26 bytes
println("1"*readInt()+"0")

Attempt This Online!
